# Redirecting users with PHP

Tags: php, html

I originally was redirecting users using headers with PHP. On my server though, I get a problem because HTML comes before the Location headers. Now, changing my script structure is not something I can do. What other ways for redirecting in my PHP can I use.

I tried these options, but they did not work:

```
echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="1; URL=index.php">";
```

Also with single quotes:

```
echo <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="1; URL=index.php">;
```

Neither ways worked. What can I do?

Comment: Use ob_start() at the start of ur PHP page

Answer (score 3):

You can [enable output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php).  The output will be buffered until it is complete, allowing you to set headers at any time.

Really though, you should fix your application so it isn't setup the way you describe.  I know you say it is not something you can do, but if you are mixing your application logic with your HTML, there are other problems you will likely run into.  Readability and reusability of your code is one.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Output Buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php).. You basically call the `ob_start()` funciton before your first output and `ob_flush()` after the last output.

Comment: For what he needs, there is no need to do this.  You can configure general buffering in php.ini.

Comment: ..which sets buffering for the whole server configuration, even if you only need it for one page/vhost/etc.. For other use-cases enabling buffering server-wide would break functionality. It is also no option at shared/paid hosting where you cannot easily change the php.ini.

Comment: Based on the question being asked, my guess is that his whole application structure is a bit foobar, and he'll be needing this elsewhere.  Also, I have yet to see a shared hosting provider where you cannot set PHP.ini directives for just your account like this.

Comment: I don't believe in setting  output buffering at the server configuration. It adds one more thing that can go wrong. 3 months later you try to add something that streams data and you keep looking for ages because the call to ob_start() doesn't point to the problem.

Comment: Fair enough.  I don't use it myself either, for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

And there is one major **fault in your php**
try this

```
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="1; URL=index.php">';
```

*Because you are already using the double quotes inside Meta tag, you must use single ones for starting and ending echo string. There you go., the Meta tag will work properly now.*

Using header

```
header('Location:http://www.mtrix.in');

exit();
```

The person will be redirected to this location provided. 
But this has to be sent before any output, or even headers are sent, because headers can be sent only once, and are generally sent before output.

You can also output the following

```
<script> 

window.location='index.php';

</script>
```

The meta tag should work

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://mtrix.in/">

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show some html content, and after some time redirect to other page. You could use the below meta tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://www.example.com/otherpage">
```

Comment: @Saurabh What do you mean? How does this relate to performance?

Comment: i meant that if we only want to redirect then why load the whole page. After that it's gonna parse and then redirect send another request. This is kind of a jerky experience. Redirects should happen on server side.

Comment: @Saurabh that's more UX than performance, but I agree. It's unfair to let the user load a page then redirect them.

Comment: @Saurabh The whole page is what you want to display, or if you just want to redirect, then you should not have any html content, only set the header, with no html content.

Comment: @Saurabh Exactly my thought. If we want to redirect immediately, then why load the page in 1st hand? and if we want to redirect after delay, it can't be done alone in server side alone though. client side will be much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didnt realise the mistake you made in the echo code, so I edited the answer, check it out, it should work now.